# Value From DialogFragment to fragment is not displaying

Tags: android, android-fragments

My Requirement:

I have **Mainfragment** class, from where I am displaying **dialogFragment** to display **seekbar**..
after adjust **seekbar** value,when click **OK** button, that value from  **dialogFragment** 
will display in **MainFragment** textview..

Here I have done below code.

**MainFragment** class:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener,OnDisplayListener {

    static TextView displayDuration;
    TextView  setDuration;

    public MainFragment() {
        }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        displayDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.displayDuration);
        setDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setDuration);
        setDuration.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            DialogFragment durationPicker = new DurationFragment();
            durationPicker.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

            }

        });
        return v;
    }



    @Override
    public void ondurationSubmit(String duration) {
        // Do stuff
        displayDuration.setText(duration);
    }
}
```

here , **OnDisplayListener** Interface :

```
public interface OnDisplayListener {
    public void ondurationSubmit(String duration);
}
```

Now **DurationFragment** fragment is:

```
public static class DurationFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    OnDisplayListener callback;
    TextView vsProgress, vs_reverseProgress = null;
    TextView levelTxt=null;

    static DurationFragment newInstance() {
    return new DurationFragment();
    }
     @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_setting2, null);
    levelTxt = (TextView) content.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    SeekBar levelSeek = (SeekBar) content.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_voice_volume);
    levelSeek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        // change to progress
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        levelTxt.setText(Integer.toString(progress) + " min");
        }
               @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
               @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
        });

        builder.setView(content);
        builder.setMessage("Your Time")
        // Positive button
        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // add value to the interface method
        callback.ondurationSubmit(levelTxt.getText().toString());
        }
        });

        return builder.create();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {


        }
    }
```

Now, From the MainFragment When It displays dialogFragment, After select seek bar value when click **Ok** button then the app stops..

saying error found :

```
callback.ondurationSubmit(levelTxt.getText().toString());
```

in this line..why the value is not displaying in mainFragment??

Comment: Where have you initialized callback in DurationFragment? You should pass in the reference of the OnDisplayListener to the DurationFragment. For example, you can do so by passing it in the constructor of DurationFragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DurationFragment add a new constructor:

```
public DurationFragment( OnDisplayListener callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

In MainFragment, in onClick do this:

```
DialogFragment durationPicker = new DurationFragment(MainFragment.this);
```

Comment: I have tried your code ..I am gettiing  java.lang.NullPointerException  error in this line:--

callback.OnDisplayListener(stringValue);

Comment: Where is this line in the code? Can you post the changes you did?

Comment: levelTxt.getText() may be returning null. Check for that.

Comment: I have tried to add a string like :-----callback.ondurationSubmit("Hello"); still same error..

Comment: Use the debugger and verify that it is indeed callback which is null. If it is, then you will have to make your Activity implement OnDisplayListener.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108801/discussion-between-raghubansh-mani-and-preeti).